# How to insert oracle database string with /n /r?

Tags: oracle, insert

I have a string with /n and /r characters. I want to insert them to Oracle database but it inserts with no /n or /r characters. Here is my code:

```
public static void SaveToDB(string body)
    {
        string connectionString = "bla bla";
        using (OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            oraConn.Open();
            OracleCommand oraCmd = new OracleCommand("CTI_DBA.CTI_DOCUMENT_PACK_TEST.CREATE_DOCUMENT");
            oraCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oraCmd.Connection = oraConn;
            OracleParameter oraParam;

            oraParam = new OracleParameter("IN_DOC_BODY", body);
            oraParam.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
            oraParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            oraCmd.Parameters.Add(oraParam);

            oraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

IN_DOC_BODY datatype is VARCHAR2(1000). I also tried to insert with OracleType.NVarChar, OracleType.Char, OracleType.NChar but nothing changed. 
Where is my problem? Any suggestions?
I

Comment: Do you mean forward slash followed by lower-case n, and forward slash followed by lower-case r? Or LF and CR control characters, which are written `\n` and `\r` (with backslashes) in the string/character syntax of some programming languages?

Comment: This works even with VARCHAR2. What is the issue?

Comment: for example mystring is "Hi\nStackOverFlow!" but it inserts "HiStackOverFlow!". I mean \n is NEWLINE character. I also tried insert into tbl(varcharcolumn) values ('SOMETHING' || chr(10)); but nothing changed

Comment: sorry henning I mean \n \r characters

Comment: How did you check it? how do you know the LF CR wasn't inserted ?

Comment: because they dont shown in the database when I get the inserted column with SELECT statement

Comment: Did you run the select in sqlplus? some other tool? Can you try to select it with `replace(IN_DOC_BODY, chr(10), 'UUUU')`?

Comment: strange. characters didn't show in db but when I use replace(IN_DOC_BODY, chr(10), 'UUUU') they replaced with UUUU. OK I understand thank you very much

Comment: answer this question and I will accept as an answer